# Click on word and get the definition...?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to have a user click on a word and a tip shows up above the word showing the definition.  The definitions will come from a glossary of words we already have. We are using Ruby and Jquery for the site.

Any suggestions or a finger pointing in a direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery then attach a click or hover event to the words container.  So if you have `<div class="WordDef">Word</div>` then you attach like;

```
$('.WordDef').click(function(){ 
  var word = $(this).text(); 
  //do postback to get definition then show definition 
})
```

Showing the definition might make another div visible that contains the definition of the word.

```
$('.DivDefinition').text("Definition of word from jQuery ajax postback");
$('.DivDefinition').show();
```

Consider using a jQuery plugin that will give you a tooltip look that you can place where the mouse was when it was clicked.

**Edit**

I found this link which might help you do an Ajax postback in rails.  I'm not a rails developer so unsure if this will help.

http://jimneath.org/2008/06/18/using-jquery-with-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Your post inspired me to opensource a plugin we use based on the tipTip plugin.

Its easy to pop open a tool tip by the mouse from a click event:

`$("#example").click(function(e){ 
$.tipTipLite('some content loaded using jQuery, not from markup', {mouse_event: e}); 
return false;
});`

You can check it out on github: http://github.com/ubermajestix/tipTipLite/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would wrap the word in a span tag, and include the definition as part of the `title` attribute. That way, users without javascript will still get a default tooltip. Making the whole thing much better from an accessibility perspective. For example:

```
<span title="Once in a while">Sporadic</span>
```

Then you can use your tooltip plugin of choice - like [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) (which uses the title attribute by default), and do something like this:

```
$('a[title]').qtip({ style: { name: 'cream', tip: true } })
```